# Filter data.frame with multiple conditions without writing them out

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I effectively filter a `data.frame` by multiple conditions without actually writing it out.

To make it more clear let us look at the following small and simplified example, where one would wish to extract all integers from 1 to 100 who fall in between either 1 and 2 or 4 and 6 or 60 and 65:

```
df <- data.frame(number = 1:100, someothermeasure = rnorm(100))
filters <- matrix(c(1,2,4,6,60,65), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

I would like the same result as below, but without listing the individual conditions by hand:

```
dplyr::filter(df, (number >= filters[1,1] & number <= filters[1,2])|(number >= filters[2,1] & number <= filters[2,2])|(number >= filters[3,1] & number <= filters[3,2]))
```

Writing it out is possible only when one has a small amount of conditions to filter over. But what to do, when the filter conditions `dim(filters)[1]` would equal for example `10000`? How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution with `rowwise()` and `filter()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(number >= filters[, 1] & number <= filters[, 2])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

or you can use `pmap_dfr()` in `purrr`, which automatically combines all filtered data by rows.

```
library(purrr)

pmap_dfr(as.data.frame(filters),
         ~ filter(df, number >= .x & number <= .y))
```

Both methods give

```
# # A tibble: 11 x 2
#    number someothermeasure
#     <int>            <dbl>
#  1      1           -0.319
#  2      2            0.497
#  3      4            0.501
#  4      5            1.20 
#  5      6           -0.741
#  6     60            0.954
#  7     61            1.59 
#  8     62            1.10 
#  9     63            0.348
# 10     64            0.242
# 11     65           -0.170
```

Comment: @Joshua I update another one, whose concept is similar to SebSta's answer but maybe more tidyverse-styled.

Comment: @ Darren Tsai, this is also a great one, did not know that function. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

`apply` is a pretty good tool to apply a function multiple times:

```
apply(X = filters, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x,y){
  y %>% 
    dplyr::filter(number >= x[1] & number <= x[2])
}, y = df)
```

Comment: thank you, good idea, I would then wrap a `do.call(rbind, )` around it.

Comment: Exactly. I wonder whether ```rbind``` or ```rbind.data.frame``` is better here, but thats a different question after all.